# Get number how many new records are added and how many are updated JPA

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa

I have the following entities:

```
public class Parent implements Serializable {

@Id
private Long propertyId;
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", orphanRemoval = true, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<Child> objects = new ArrayList<>();
```

And the child class:

```
public class Child implements Serializable {

@Id
@NotNull
private Long childId;

@Id
@JoinColumn(name = "parent_id")
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Parent parent;
```

I am getting the data from a another api in csv file, parsing it and persisting it.
The way I persist the data is:

1. First creating the Parent objects from the csv file
2. Creating the Child objects from the csv file
3. Set for every Parent the list of children and for every children set the parent

In the end I have the following code that persists the data:

```
parentRepository.saveAll(parents);
```

where parents is the complete list where I have the complete data.

I am calling this api from time to time, which means every time is called there might be new data or the same but in the end I must persist it.
What is my question is how to track how many new records are added and how many records are updated. I know that I can do some filter thing and query every entity and check if it exists but since I have around 80 000 entites adding so many queries is really time consuming.

Any proposal of how to do this but not to be so time consuming? Is there any kind of interceptor that will maybe give me the data at the end of the query?

Comment: jow do you understand if it is creation or update. if on create, you do not have propertyId and on update if you have propertyId, then you can simply have a loop on your data if properyId is null or not. So, you can understand how many creation or update has added. Hope, i got what you need.

Comment: I am always getting the property id, because I am not auto generating it. And this is what makes the task harder. I am getting record with property id but if it exist jpa will update it but if it doesn't exist it will be persisted as new.

Comment: then maybe you can keep the old used propertyId's on a list. then check if contains the propertyId. so, you can know how many data has created or how many are updated. You know,if the list does not contain the propertyId, it means it is creation. This is the only way, come to mind , doing it without another query or queries.

Comment: It can happen that the propertyId is in the list but the property object is different and in that case jpa will update it. So it won't be a new record. And I think it's not a good idea to keep it in the list. You don't know when the garbage collector will remove that list.

Comment: Sorry, i do not have any other idea for doing that without query.

Answer (score 1):

**Some background:**

- When you use manually assigned ids, If the object you are sending already exists, hibernate does not issue insert or update.
- The reason for this is that whenever you call `save()` on entities with manually assigned ids, hibernate first does a select to decide if it is `insert` or `update`.
- But since it has already done a select, it can compare it to decide if they are exactly equal, in that case, it will not issue `insert` or `update`
- You can verify this behaviour by adding `spring.jpa.show-sql=true`, `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true` and
  `logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG` to `application.properties`

**Solution**

- Add the following fields and methods to your entity

```
    @Transient
    private boolean updated;

    @Transient
    private boolean created;

    @PrePersist
    public void setCreated() {
        this.created = true;
    }

    @PreUpdate
    public void setUpdated() {
        this.updated = true;
    }

    public boolean isCreated() {
        return created;
    }

    public boolean isUpdated() {
        return updated;
    }
```

- After `saveAll()` ,

  - `parent.isCreated()` is true, then you know it is new insert
  - `parent.isUpdated()` is true, then you know it is update
  - If both are false, then insert or update didn't happen